# List ASIO audio out devices in NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio, asio

How do I list ASIO audio output devices using NAudio library?

For WaveIn, it would be:

```
int devcount = WaveIn.DeviceCount;
for (int c= 0; c < devcount; c++)
{
    WaveInCapabilities info = WaveIn.GetCapabilities(c);
    Console.Out.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", info.ProductName, info.Channels);
}
```

For WASAPI, it would be:

```
MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
foreach (MMDevice device in enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.All))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", device.FriendlyName, device.State);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the implementation of the AsioOutSettingsPanel class](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudioDemo/AudioPlaybackDemo/AsioOutSettingsPanel.cs), ASIO driver names are used as device names. So, the `AsioOut.GetDriverNames()` method can be used.